# installation of admin actions extension Openstack while Suspen/Resume action

Tags: openstack, jclouds, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I am trying to resume/ suspend a node already created in openstack using Jcloud APIs.
The node gets resumed/suspended if i check it on my openstack server GUI, But my code gets an error response saying "Suspend requires installation of Admin action extensions".

I checked my policy.json on openstack server it has the resume and suspend extensions mentioned with Admin as Role.

Any idea how to rectify it, or what might be required to do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-594) that has already been fixed in jclouds. It will be included in the next release or you can try our daily snapshot builds, see the "Using the daily builds" section of the [Installation Guide](http://jclouds.apache.org/start/install/).

Answer (score 0):

I've surrounded the method call with try/catch and treated the exception, like:

```
try {
    computeService.suspendNode(nodeId);
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The suspend/resume/reboot calls works just fine.

I'm using JClouds VIEW layer implementation beside specific provider API layer, by the way.
With DevStack/OpenStack.